# How to redirect where my localhost points to?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I have `http://localhost/` pointing to a folder where there's nothing in it. I'm assuming the previous developer hosted from there. I, on the other hand, host from xampp and my websites are in `C:\xampp\htdocs` . In order to display my sites I have to go to `http://localhost:39020/` instead. This may not be a huge issue, but I am wondering, how do I reset this so that my `http://localhost/` points to the xampp location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find and kill whatever process is listening on port 80, then configure your server to listen on port 80.

Comment: cool, can you elaborate on this please? Where do I find these settings? I'm not much of an IT (hardware) person

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I did that. My xampp/conf/httpd.conf. has always been Listen 80. But somehow, it results in error

Comment: That's because some other process is using port 80.  You need to find it and terminate it.

Comment: actually, I stopped and restarted xampp and it redirected! That's good news! Thanks